# R plotly ignoring text label alignment hjust

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

I am using plotly 4.8 with ggplot2 3.0.0, and trying to add and align text labels to my scatter plots. However, it seems the `hjust` parameter is being ignored by plotly in `geom_text(aes(....), hjust = "left")`. (Also tried `hjust = 0`.)

**GGPLOT OUTPUT**

See it renders fine in plot window as a ggplot with labels left aligned.

[image: ggplot left align chart example]

**PLOTLY OUTPUT**

But the alignment is lost in conversion, and the text is centered.

[image: plotly center chart example]

So the question, is fixing this alignment possible with plotly?

**TEST EXAMPLE CODE**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

data(mtcars)

plotdata <- as.data.table(mtcars)
plotdata$carname <- rownames(mtcars)

# take a small demo subset
plotdata <- plotdata[1:10,]

gg <- ggplot(plotdata, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, label = carname)) +  
               geom_point()  + theme_minimal()
gg <- gg + geom_text(aes(label = carname),
                       size = 2,
                       hjust = "left")
print(gg)

# convert ggplot
p <- ggplotly(gg)
p
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to add text position `textposition = "right"`:

```
ggplotly(p) %>% style(textposition = "right")
```

Output:

[image: Output from Plotly]

Ref: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/769

Comment: I knew it had to be easy... Brilliant Saurabh!

Comment: @micstr: Thank you. May be not Brilliant as you :)